# Video file uploading

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and I followed a tutorial that shows how to upload a video file.
At this moment it uses move_uploaded_file function but it doesn't work, the file is not shown in "videos" folder. Can somebody explain to me why the file isn't showing up?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Upload System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include "connect.php";
?>

<div id='box'>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php


        if(isset($_FILES['video'])){ 

        $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
        $type = explode('.', $name);
        $type = end($type);
        $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
        $random_name = rand();
        $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

        if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'MP4' && $type != 'flv'){
            $message = "Video Foramt Not Supported!";

            }else{

            move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type);
            $message = "Successfully Uploaded";

            }
            echo "$message <br/><br>";

        }


    ?> 
        Select Video: <br/>
        <input type='file' name='video' />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' value='Upload' />
    </form>
</div>

<div id='box'>
    <?php





    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your error log say? That will usually tell you why writing a file fails.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` returns a boolean - you can check the return value to see if it worked or not. At a guess, I'd say that you might want to use an absolute path instead of `'videos/'`, and I'd also check the permissions on that directory

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logs? How large is the file being uploaded? Smaller than the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size configuration settings in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if uploaded successfully..

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type)) {
    $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
}
```

I suspect the path you have provided is not valid, tough.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to check the php.ini file to see the upload file (video) size limit and increase it, or just try to upload a small size file.